# How to align the "options" to the "select" of kendo dropdownlist?

Tags: jquery, html, css, kendo-ui, kendo-dropdown

I'm using the kendo ui dropdownlist and I noticed that the options do not align with the select when the select is cut off from the viewport. This is what happens:

[image]

Is there any way to make the options align with the select in this scenario? I want the options to be cut off from the screen also.

Thank you!

PS:
The kendo dropdown can be seen here: http://demos.kendoui.com/web/dropdownlist/events.html

Comment: Can you provide jsfiddle link to your code with the issue in question?

Comment: @NathanLee i just provided the demo for the kendo ui dropdownlist

Comment: But that is aligning fine, But I need to know the issue in your code that is not allowing it to align properly - @dork

Comment: @NathanLee resize your browser window to mimic the picture I attached in my question :)

Comment: @dork I edited my answer; hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

Well - it's not a bug, it's a feature.

You'd have to rewrite the `_position` method in the Popup widget (kendo.ui.popup).

Alternative:
I came across this in another context; you can prevent the dropdown from changing position by setting `kendo.ui.Popup.fn.options.collision` to `false` (this will affect all widgets which use Popup):

```
kendo.ui.Popup.fn.options.collision = false;

var data = [{
    text: "Item1",
    value: "1"
}, {
    text: "Item2",
    value: "2"
}, {
    text: "Item3",
    value: "3"
}];

$("#dropdownlist").kendoDropDownList({
    dataTextField: "text",
    dataValueField: "value",
    dataSource: data
});
```

([demo](http://jsbin.com/UWaLEPUs/2/edit))